# How to calculate amount of USDC to withdraw based on price of WMatic in solidity

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I have a common problem while converting a 18 decimal WMatic to a 6 decimal USDC price on polygon mainnet. I have the following scenario:

I took a flash loan of 70 WMatic from Aave.
I deposited that 70 WMatic + 30 WMatic (from my wallet) to a lending platform like Compound III.
After successfully depositing to Compound III, I want to borrow some USDC based on my collateral (Compound III doesn't allow borrowing & deposit of the same token), which I will swap to WMatic to payback the flash loan (with some fees).

So my question here is how can I calculate the exact amount of USDC I should borrow to successfully payback the flash loan in solidity?

I have tried it several times but end up calculating wrong amount in solidity.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the DEX you will use to swap. If you go for UniV2 (or a fork), you can use this method:

```
uint256 amountOut = 70 ether;  // the amount of WMATIC you need
(uint256 reserveIn, uint256 reserveOut) = UniswapV2Library.getReserves(FACTORY_ADDRESS, USDC_ADDRESS, WMATIC_ADDRESS);
uint256 amountIn = UniswapV2Library.getAmountIn(amountOut, reserveIn, reserveOut);
```

(You need to import [UniswapV2Library](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol) in your contract.)

In any case, I don't think Chainlink is useful here. Also you don't have to care about the decimals of the token. To borrow `amountIn` USDC from Compound you can use something like:

```
cUSDC.borrow(amountIn);
```

and to make the swap you can use the `swapTokensForExactTokens` of the router.